# Are Variables & This considered implicit scopes inside a CFC in CF2016?

Tags: coldfusion, scope, cfml, coldfusion-2016

What does it take, to take advantage of the performance gain from [ColdFusion 2016's new setting `searchImplicitScopes="false"`](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/whats-new-cf-2016.html):

> ... bypasses searching for a variable in the implicit scopes thus
>   finding the variables defined in the application faster.

Should we start scoping `Variables` & `This` scopes inside a CFC with `searchImplicitScopes="false"` in ColdFusion 2016?

I cannot find any documentation on what are considered implicit scopes in CF2016.  I am pretty sure `local` and `arguments` scopes are fine inside a function, but what about frequently used scopes like `variables` and `this` in a CFC?

Comment: Sorry - I did not see your answer was version specific.

Answer (score 3):

**Scope all the things!!!**

The `variables` scope inside a CFC is global to all functions inside the CFC.

The `this` scope inside a CFC is global to all functions inside the CFC and can also be referenced from the caller of the CFC.

If you do not scope a variable inside a CFC, it defaults to the `variables` scope.
`<--- this_test.cfc --->
<cfcomponent>
    <cfset variables.foo = "This is my CFC global variable." />
    <cfset this.bar = "This variable is global to my CFC and can be referenced externally." />
    <cfset narf = "Global variable! Point!" />
    <cffunction name="getNarf" access="public">
        <cfreturn narf />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>`

Test call:
`<cfset test = new this_test() />`

<cfoutput>
    <li>#test.foo#</li>
    <li>#test.bar#</li>
    <li>#test.narf#</li>
    <li>#test.getNarf()#</li>
</cfoutput>

1. `foo` is in the `variables` scope, you'll get an error: `Element FOO is undefined in TEST.`
2. `bar` is in the `this` scope, so you get the output for `test.bar`.
3. `narf` is in the `variables` scope, you'll get an error: `Element NARF is undefined in TEST.`
4. The only way to get the value of `narf` is to have a function return it.

**Update**

That `searchImplicitScopes` can turn off CF's scope search capability. So if you don't scope something, it won't look up the hierarchy of scopes. Question is, does an un-scoped variable end up in the `variables` scope by default? I would say, yes, as that's been the default since CFCs debuted.

Regardless of using that setting, I still say scope everything. The whole reason they created the implicit `local` scope was because:

1. developers weren't used to `var` scoping function local variables
2. developers that were, tended to do `var local = structNew()`, so they only had to `var` scope one variable.
3. 2 also gave them the ability to return the collection of function local variables.
4. As of CF 9, when `var a = 0` became the same as `local.a = 0`, you could remove all instances of `var local = structNew()`, so long as you also "scoped" and referenced those private variables as `local.a`.

**The bottom line**

is that there is some performance overhead if CF has to look up variable scopes on every request. If you turned off that lookup using `searchImplicitScopes=false`, you should get some performance boost. But then, that should really rely on your application and average request load.

Comment: scope all the things? even `local` and `arguments`?  Sorry I just rephrased my question to make it clear that I am asking what does it take to take advantage of the performance gain in CF2016's `searchImplicitScopes=false`.

Comment: Scope every thing. even `local` and `arguments`

Comment: @AdrianJMoreno "I would say, yes" would you be able to confirm that?  I don't have CF2016 installed yet.  I may post my answer tomorrow when I find out.

Answer (score 1):

Just installed CF 2016 Express and I can conclude that with `searchImplicitScopes="false"`, the `Variables` scope is still being searched when a variable is not scoped, but not the `This` scope.